# How to point Kubernetes secrets to Configmap

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

We are trying integrate our workflow service with SSO(using OKTA for OIDC). now I got Okta ClientID and Secret key. Need to update the workflow configmap with K8 secrets.

I created K8 secrets with the below commands but my configmap is not picking up them. Can you please point me what I am missing?

```
kubectl create secret -n argo generic client-id-secret --from-literal=client-id-key=xyuawyeioweh
kubectl create secret -n argo generic client-secret-secret --from-literal=client-secret-key=xxxxxxxxxxx
```

This is my configmap:

```
sso: |
    issuer: https://xxxxxx
    clientId:
      name: client-id-secret
      key: xxxxxxxxx
    clientSecret:
      name: client-secret-secret
      key: xxxxxxxxxxxx
    redirectUrl: https://workflows.apps/oauth2/callback
```

Thank you
CS

Comment: Use those Secrets **instead** of the ConfigMap. It is easier to answer if you show your Deployment yaml so we can suggest how you should use Secrets instead.

Comment: You should include the secrets inside of your deployment not inside of your ConfigMap, they should be configured in the same way as a ConfigMap

Comment: [Secrets](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/) are not the same as [ConfigMaps](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/configmap/).
Can you share your manifest files with us ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are trying to call secret inside the config map.
You can not do so. In Kubernetes world, both are separate objects and you have to use them in pod/deployment etc definition.

In your above scenario, mount/use the secrets in the deployment/pod and have some script to read those inside pods and populate your sso configuration with the same.

Share your deployment YAML for more accurate answer.